# Print Multiple key value pair in single line using sed or awk

Tags: unix, awk, sed

```
My input: ps -ef|grep mysql

    --defaults-file=/xyz/ --basedir=name --datadir=/data  --user=abc--log-error=/log1 --port=1211
    --defaults-file=/mno/ --basedir=anothername --datadir=/data2  --user=pqr --log-error=/log2 --port=1212
```

I tried following command

```
ps -ef|grep mysql| awk 'BEGIN {RS=" "}; /--port/' 
output:

--port=1211
--port=1212
```

How do i get specific key valur pair using a single awk command? Output should be like this

```
port:1211
base dir:name
log dir:log1

port:1212
base dir:anothername
log dir:log2
```

Comment: It is not at clear, you have to post 3 simple things. 1- sample of input, 2- sample of output and 3rd most important thing your efforts which you have put in order to solve your problem. Kindly add these and let us know then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure your sed version, try this:

```
sed -e '/port=/{' -e 'h;s/.*--port=\([0-9]*\)\s*$/port:\1/;x;s/.*--basedir=\([^ ]*\).*--log-error=.\([^ ]*\).*/base dir:\1\nlog dir:\2\n/;H;x}'
```

`--posix` tested working.

Comment: @user6690412  Glad to know that it helped :)